# REQUEST_FILENAME consider requset as real file in live server but in local consider it as not file

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have this htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>     
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^(mdiet|user)($|/) - [L]
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
   RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(\.css|\.js|\.png|\.jpg|\.gif|robots\.txt)$ [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ route.php?q=$1 [NC,QSA,L] 
</IfModule>
```

When call this url in localhost: `http://localhost:8080/comm_cvs/comm/web/group_items` 
the htaccess undestand that group_items is not file and redirect the request to route.php and everything went ok.

but when move the code to server: the behaivior is not as we expected

when call: www.mysite.com/group_items => htaccess consider it as file and go to group_items.php directly without redirect it to route.php.

what's the problem in live server??